# How to create a fallback placeholder for <use xlink:href /> in SVG/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Our team use SVG's `<use xlink:href />` for shared SVG assets in our web pages. Here is a minimal example:

```html
<div id="page-content">
    <span>This is a blue square, isn't it?</span> <br />
    <svg width="28" height="28">
        <use
            xlink:href="#our-team-shared-square"
            style="color: blue;"
        />
    </svg>
</div>

<!-- this svg can be inlined or loaded and inserted into the DOM dynamically -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none">
    <symbol id="our-team-shared-square" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
        <path d="M 4 4 H 24 V 24 H 4 Z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="our-team-shared-something-else" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
        <!-- ... -->
    </symbol>

    <!-- and more others  -->
</svg>
```

It is a powerful technique, but it has some pitfalls too: the ID in the `xlink:href` attribute could be misprinted or the big svg with shared symbols could be failed to load. In both cases there will no symbol on a page corresponding to the specified ID, and the `<use />` will be rendered as an empty block.

In order to mitigate the problem we want to provide fallback placeholders for shared SVG assets.

```html
<!-- something like this  -->
<svg width="28" height="28">
    <text>�</text>  <!-- your fonts are okay, this is U+FFFD character :)  -->
    <use xlink:href="#our-team-shared-symbol" style="..." />
</svg>

<!-- or like this  -->
<div class="our-svg-asset">
    <svg width="28" height="28">
        <use xlink:href="#our-team-shared-symbol" style="..." />
    </svg>
    <span>�</span>
</div>
```

But we need a way to **detect whether the ID** in the `xlink:href` attribute **matches to some symbol** on a page.

What do we think it might look like?

- Some tricky CSS-selector, which matches with the `svg` tag, only if there is some visual content inside it (or opposite, only if there is an ID matching error inside the `svg` tag).
- Some SVG layout magic, which make the successfully matched `use` tag to shift the placeholder and make it effectively invisible.
- Some JS DOM API (the least desirable way), which allow to check if the `<use xlink:href />` inside the given SVG tag is successfully matched to some SVG symbol.

It is quite likely there may exist another unimaginable for us ways to toggle such a fallback placeholder. :)

We hope to find a JS-less solution, but look forward to any suitable solution.

Thank you.

Comment: If your `id` attribute is wrong, then that is a bug you would want to know about, correct. Using a fallback would mask the fault.  And re the fallback placeholder, what do you anticipate that look like?  Something like the HTML broken image icon?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yes, it is definitely a mistake. But we have a lot of developers in company, a lot of web pages and a lot of shared assets and places where they are used. So we cannot just expect mistakes to never happen. :)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau A fallback placeholder can be some Unicode character (as in the my example), or some inlined CSS beauty, or even base64-encoded and inlined image (well, theoretically).

Comment: Sounds like your developers need to create some unit tests or you run some automated integration/acceptance tests that would catch this e.g. run selenium to find all the use elements then check all the ids they point to are reachable.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, and they do. But it is hard to cover all pages and all cases during extensive development in a big company. We want to have a bullet-proof fallback, just in case.

Comment: Testing is for teams that provide too complex tools to junior developers. Whack complex code in a native Web Component, so juniors **only use**: ``<svg-asset symbol="...">`` . For inspiration on loading SVG content see: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman It is a great idea to encapsulate the fallback code in a component! But how can we check in the component that it refers to an external asset which does not exist?

Comment: Learn to work with ``.catch(error)`` in the ``.fetch`` API call

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman We have plenty of `<use xlink:href />` tags which refer to assets in many `<svg />` packs. Our question is not how to use Fetch API and Promise's `.catch()`. Our question is how to detect whether the `xlink:href` value in the given `<use />` tag refers to an absent asset. Moreover, in the case when `<svg />` pack with assets is inlined, Fetch API and Promises does nothing to help (but ID in a `xlink:href` still can be invalid).

Comment: Write a Web Component that (maybe only in dev mode) injects the SVG, extracts the HREF values, tries to load them and report failures. And yes, that diverts a bit of the unit testing work to your component. Its like those new valves that always monitor your tire pressure.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thank you for the awesome idea! But is not really the answer to our current question. :)

Comment: https://i.imgflip.com/46r55m.jpg